# Not able to bind dependency property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a very simple WPF Application which has a slider and a button.
I am trying to bind one of the properties in my class to the value of the slider and displaying the value in a messagebox whenever the button is clicked.

I have a property called BattingForm in my Player class

```
<Window.Resources>

    <local:Player x:Key="_batsman" x:Name="_batsman"
                  BattingForm="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=Form}">
    </local:Player>

</Window.Resources>

<Slider Maximum="1" LargeChange="0.25" Value="0.25" Name="Form"/>
```

And inside the Player Class, the property is as follows.

```
    public double BattingForm
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(BattingFormProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BattingFormProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BattingFormProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BattingForm", typeof(double), typeof(Player));
```

And in the MainWindow.xaml.cs inside the buttonclick event, I try to access it as follows -

```
        Player batsman = FindResource("_batsman") as Player;
        if(batsman!=null)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(batsman.BattingForm.ToString());
        }
```

In the MessageBox it only shows 0, not the actual value of the Slider.

Comment: Why is your `Player` control declared as a resource and not as a part of your window?

Comment: @AdiLester Player is not a control, it is simply a class with a property in it.

Comment: In that case, why do you need it in XAML? You could simply access the slider's value from code-behind with `Form.Value`.

Comment: @AdiLester I know that, but I really want to learn databinding and dependency properties for complex applications I make later on.

Comment: OK then, first lesson: Data binding doesn't happen for resources until you actually use them - that's why you get value = 0. I think you'd be able to learn better if you try doing something specific rather than arbitrary testing.

Comment: @AdiLester Do you know how I can use it outside of the resources, a quick and dirty trick for now, because I dont know how to use it outside of the resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily declare the binding on the Slider instead of the Player resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Player x:Key="batsman" BattingForm="0.25"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Slider Maximum="1" LargeChange="0.25"
            Value="{Binding BattingForm, Source={StaticResource batsman}}"/>
</Grid>
```

This works because the `Value` property of the Slider binds two-way by default. If it wouldn't do that, you would have to set the TwoWay mode explicitly:

```
<Slider Maximum="1" LargeChange="0.25"
        Value="{Binding BattingForm, Source={StaticResource batsman}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: It looks like he's trying to set the Player's value from the Slider, not the other way around.

Comment: Doesn't really matter in a two-way binding, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Data binding won't happen for the `Player` control until it's actually used. Currently, you've only declared your `_batsman` resource but haven't actually used it.

As you said you're only doing this for testing, the simplest thing to do would be to derive `Player` from a base class that can be used in XAML, like a `Control`:

```
public class Player : Control
```

Then you'll be able to do this in XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Slider Maximum="1" LargeChange="0.25" Value="0.25" Name="Form"/>

    <local:Player x:Name="_batsman"
                  BattingForm="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=Form}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I already have DependencyObject as the base class, so it does not allow me to have two base classes. But the other answers worked so np and thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: `Control` is derived from `DependencyObject`, so you can just derive from `Control`.

Answer (score 2):

Try reversing your bindings:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Player x:Key="_batsman" BattingForm="0.25" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Slider Maximum="1.0" LargeChange="0.25" Value="{Binding BattingForm, Source={StaticResource _batsman}}" />
        <!-- Included for testing -->
        <TextBox Text="{Binding BattingForm, Source={StaticResource _batsman}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```